# Orbeon Forms: Setting Background Colour on Focus

Tags: orbeon

We know we can set the background colour on an **Text** and **Plain Text** fields via the following CSS style code:

```
.xforms-input input:focus {color: black !important; background-color: blue !important; }  
.xforms-textarea textarea:focus {color: black !important; background-color: pink !important; }
```

But how do we do the same for:

- Number fields
- Formatted text area
- Currency fields
- 

Many thanks in advance

PeteA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following adds the cases of the currency, number, and formatted text area controls to your CSS.

```css
.xforms-input    input:focus,
.xforms-textarea textarea:focus,
.xbl-fr-currency input:focus,
.xbl-fr-number   input:focus,
.xbl-html-input.mce-edit-focus
    {color: black !important; background-color: pink !important; }
```

PS: I highly recommend using your browser's Dev Tools to find about those classes, and experiment "live" with CSS.

Comment: Thanks Alex,
I have been playing around with the Dev Tools, but I couldn't work out how to get the data.
But I still struggling on how to get the data from the Dev Tools.. Ideally we want the "focus" settings for all controls.
Example form: https://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/89b743793ff4ea108b2769a0c2d4f1a862e84aa7

Comment: @PeteAtkin For most controls (the first four lines in the CSS above), you will have an HTML `input`, `textarea`, or other HTML field that you want to target, inside an element that has a class that tells you about the control type (e.g. `.xforms-input', `.xbl-fr-currency'...). The case of the formatted text area is a bit odd in the sense that it doesn't use a native form element, hence the special `mce-edit-focus` class added by TinyMCE.